# Contact form not sending [html, php, js]

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to send e-mail using this contact form but i can't get it to work. It's outputing that is sent but i m not getting any. Tested sending mail with simple php form and i'm getting mail just fine so it's not server i presume.
Any explanation highly appreciated.

```
<form id="contact-form" action="email.php" method="post" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="contact-box-hide">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" required placeholder="First Name">
                            <span class="first-name-error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" required placeholder="Last Name">
                            <span class="last-name-error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control"  id="contact_email" name="contact_email" required placeholder="Email Address">
                            <span class="contact-email-error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="subject" name="contact_subject" required placeholder="Subject">
                            <span class="contact-subject-error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            <span class="contact-message-error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <button id="contact-submit" class="btn custom-btn col-xs-12" type="submit" name="submit"><a href=""></a><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></button>
                            <span id="contact-loading" class="btn custom-btn col-xs-12"> <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.contact-box-hide -->
                    <div class="contact-message"></div>

                </form><!-- /#contact-form -->
```

php

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['first_name'] == '' || $_REQUEST['contact_email'] == '' ||        $_REQUEST['message'] == ''):
return "error";
endif;
if (filter_var($_REQUEST['contact_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)):
$subject = 'Contact form'; // Subject of your email

// Receiver email address
$to = 'mail@domain.com';  //Change the email address by yours


// prepare header
$header = 'From: '. $_REQUEST['first_name'] . " " .$_REQUEST['last_name'] . '       <'. $_REQUEST['contact_email'] .'>'. "\r\n";
$header .= 'Reply-To:  '. $_REQUEST['first_name'] . " "  .$_REQUEST['last_name'] . ' <'. $_REQUEST['contact_email'] .'>'. "\r\n";
$header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


$message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['first_name'] . " " .$_REQUEST['last_name'] . "\n";
$message .= 'Email: ' . $_REQUEST['contact_email'] . "\n";
$message .= 'Subject: ' . $_REQUEST['contact_subject'] . "\n";
$message .= 'Message: '. $_REQUEST['message'];

// Send contact information
$mail = mail( $to, $subject , $message, $header );

 echo 'sent';
else:
 return "error";
endif; 

?>
```

js

```
$('#contact-submit').click(function () {
    $('.first-name-error, .last-name-error, .contact-email-error, .contact-subject-error, .contact-message-error').hide();
    var first_nameVal = $('input[name=first_name]').val();
    var last_nameVal = $('input[name=last_name]').val();
    var emailReg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/igm;
    var emailVal = $('#contact_email').val();
    var contact_subjectVal = $('input[name=contact_subject]').val();
    var messageVal = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    //validate

    if (first_nameVal == '' || first_nameVal == 'First Name *') {
        $('.first-name-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> First name is required.').fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
    if (last_nameVal == '' || last_nameVal == 'Last Name *') {
        $('.last-name-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Last name is required.').fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
    if (emailVal == "" || emailVal == "Email Address *") {

        $('.contact-email-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Your email address is required.').fadeIn();
        return false;

    } else if (!emailReg.test(emailVal)) {

        $('.contact-email-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Invalid email address.').fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
     if (contact_subjectVal == '' || contact_subjectVal == 'Subject *') {
        $('.contact-subject-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Subject is required.').fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
    if (messageVal == '' || messageVal == 'Message *') {
        $('.contact-message-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Please provide a message.').fadeIn();
        return false;
    }

    var data_string = $('.contact-form').serialize();

    $('#contact-submit').hide();
    $('#contact-loading').fadeIn();
    $('.contact-error-field').fadeOut();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "email.php",
        data: data_string,

        //success
        success: function (data) {

            $('.contact-box-hide').slideUp();
            $('.contact-message').html('<i class="fa fa-check contact-success"></i><div>Your message has been sent.</div>').fadeIn();
        },
        error: function (data) {

            $('.btn-contact-container').hide();
            $('.contact-message').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation contact-error"></i><div>Something went wrong, please try again later.</div>').fadeIn();
        }

    }) //end ajax call
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you checked the error logs? for the PHP add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` For the jQuery, watch the request / resposnse in the browser's console.

Comment: I think it's better to use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST

Comment: Your aJax isn't actually showing back any response from the PHP. have you alerted out the data in the success call to see if it shows sent or error as output in your PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You will always get message "sent" because you didnt check whether mail is sent or not, so add additional "if-else" to check mail is sent, code shown below 
>  Also there is an error in php, remove "." from message(only once) else $message wont be initialized. Found another error in js, you have called a class instead of id 
> Corrected all, and updated code below

```
       <?php
    if($_REQUEST['first_name'] == '' || $_REQUEST['contact_email'] == '' ||        $_REQUEST['message'] == ''):
        return "error";
    endif;
    if (filter_var($_REQUEST['contact_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)):
        $subject = 'Contact form'; // Subject of your email

        // Receiver email address
        $to = 'mail@domain.com';  //Change the email address by yours


        // prepare header
        $header = 'From: '. $_REQUEST['first_name'] . " " .$_REQUEST['last_name'] . '       <'. $_REQUEST['contact_email'] .'>'. "\r\n";
        $header .= 'Reply-To:  '. $_REQUEST['first_name'] . " "  .$_REQUEST['last_name'] . ' <'. $_REQUEST['contact_email'] .'>'. "\r\n";
        $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


        $message= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['first_name'] . " " .$_REQUEST['last_name'] . "\n";
        $message.= 'Email: ' . $_REQUEST['contact_email'] . "\n";
        $message.= 'Subject: ' . $_REQUEST['contact_subject'] . "\n";
        $message.= 'Message: '. $_REQUEST['message'];

        // Send contact information
        $mail = mail( $to, $subject , $message, $header );
        if($mail) {   // added if-else check
            echo 'sent';
        }
        else
        {
            echo "mail couldnt send";
        }
    else:
        return "error";
    endif;

    ?>
```

Now replace your js code with this(shown below)

```
     <script>
            $('#contact-submit').click(function () {
                $('.first-name-error, .last-name-error, .contact-email-error, .contact-subject-error, .contact-message-error').hide();
                var first_nameVal = $('input[name=first_name]').val();
                var last_nameVal = $('input[name=last_name]').val();
                var emailReg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/igm;
                var emailVal = $('#contact_email').val();
                var contact_subjectVal = $('input[name=contact_subject]').val();
                var messageVal = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

                //validate

                if (first_nameVal == '' || first_nameVal == 'First Name *') {
                    $('.first-name-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> First name is required.').fadeIn();
                    return false;
                }
                if (last_nameVal == '' || last_nameVal == 'Last Name *') {
                    $('.last-name-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Last name is required.').fadeIn();
                    return false;
                }
                if (emailVal == "" || emailVal == "Email Address *") {

                    $('.contact-email-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Your email address is required.').fadeIn();
                    return false;

                } else if (!emailReg.test(emailVal)) {

                    $('.contact-email-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Invalid email address.').fadeIn();
                    return false;
                }
                if (contact_subjectVal == '' || contact_subjectVal == 'Subject *') {
                    $('.contact-subject-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Subject is required.').fadeIn();
                    return false;
                }
                if (messageVal == '' || messageVal == 'Message *') {
                    $('.contact-message-error').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Please provide a message.').fadeIn();
                    return false;
                }

                var data_string = $('#contact-form').serialize();
    console.log(data_string);
                $('#contact-submit').hide();
                $('#contact-loading').fadeIn();
                $('.contact-error-field').fadeOut();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "email.php",
                    data: data_string,

                    //success
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("response from php is"+data);
                        if(data == "sent")  //success
                        {
                            $('.contact-box-hide').slideUp();
                            $('.contact-message').html('<i class="fa fa-check contact-success"></i><div>Your message has been sent.</div>').fadeIn();
                        }
                        else  // anything other than sent will be error
                        {
                            $('.btn-contact-container').hide();
                            $('.contact-message').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation contact-error"></i><div>Something went wrong, please try again later.</div>').fadeIn();
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log("ajax failed");
                        $('.btn-contact-container').hide();
                        $('.contact-message').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation contact-error"></i><div>Something went wrong, please try again later.</div>').fadeIn();
                    }

                }); //end ajax call


                return false;
            });





        </script>
```

**Screenshot submitted**
[image]

Comment: Just to also add to your response, the aJax is also not reading the response back from the PHP in the success call

Comment: @Domagoj..did you add semi-colon at the end? like this 


}); //end ajax call...... and please tell what error u see in console

Comment: Fixed javascript, i dont get any errors and console is blank. PHP isn't right i guess cause it's not sending.

Comment: @Domagoj..check my ajax code, i have updated and added a console code...this time js will show whats the error in console...

Comment: Showing error with first_name on line 3 PHP Undefined index

Comment: @Domagoj...please check my updated answer, i have tested entire code, fixed all errors...im sure this will work :) and pls dont forget to vote up :) thanks

Comment: Thank you !!! I owe you a beer for saving my hairline :) And lightning fast too! +, liked your fb page since my vote here is meaningless :D

Answer (score 0):

You are printing 'sent' even if the mail() function fails.

```
// Send contact information
$mail = mail( $to, $subject , $message, $header );

// Check the return value of mail()
if ($mail)
    echo 'sent';
else
    echo 'error';
// End of check

else:
 return "error";

endif;
```